# Windows10 NT Shell ，using WPF Application to replace Explorer.exe

Tags: wpf, windows-10, registry, windows-nt

My program can't start normally after boot，but **Mark Text** can start normally.

Whether I'm replacing it directly or through the Eshell.exe.

[Mark Text](https://github.com/marktext/marktext/)

Did I miss something?

---

**C++ Application can also start,WPF can't start**

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really give much to go on.

I am guessing you want to [Enable and Configure a Shell Launcher.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/iot-ent-shell-launcher-app-launcher)

In the link they give the example as follows;

```
$ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\localhost\root\standardcimv2\embedded:WESL_UserSetting"

$ShellLauncherClass.SetDefaultShell("notepad.exe",1)

$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)
```

Here [is another resource on How to configure shell launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher)